# Possible improper enforcement of 200-rep cap after question migration

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, reputation

Apologies if this is a dupe...

Today on Christianity.SE, I reached the 200 rep cap.  Then a question I answered got migrated to Philosophy.SE, along with ~70 of my rep.  Since that time, I've had several more upvotes, but they continue to get 0 rep, as though I had still met the 200 rep cap.

Is this by design, or a bug?

If the answer is "Bug, but it's too insignificant to matter," that's fine, too. :)

Comment: Have you tried [recalc-ing](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/reputation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rep recalc is now performed in these cases, syncing up the rep cap within 5 minutes of the migration being completed.

Answer (score 4):

This is by design.  It should all shake out with a rep recalc.  If you go to https://christianity.stackexchange.com/reputation you should see a button at the very bottom to request an immediate rep recalc, give that a shot.

Do note, though, that the recalc will trim off any other rep earned by other migrated / deleted questions and whatnot.